# AndroidのアプリインストールIntentでFileUriExposedExceptionによりアプリが落ちる

Tags: android, android-studio

現在アプリを更新するシステムの作成をしているのですが、エラーが検出されます。
しかし、このエラーはAndroid 6.0.1の実機では発生すらせずAndroid O のエミュレータで検出されました。

```
    public void download() {
    try {
        // URL設定
        URL url = new URL("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0Bxp5wIuQibuSdU1BOWl0QUFVR0U");
        // HTTP接続開始
        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.connect();

        // SDカードの設定
        String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MCPEBackups/tmp/";
        File file = new File(PATH);
        file.mkdirs();

        // テンポラリファイルの設定
        File outputFile = new File(file, "MCPEBackup.apk");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        // ダウンロード開始
        InputStream is = c.getInputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len = 0;
        while ((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        fos.close();
        is.close();
        // Intent生成
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        // MIME type設定
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MCPEBackups/tmp/" + "MCPEBackup.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        // Intent発行
        startActivity(intent);//412行目
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

エラーコードはこちらです。

```
    06-02 13:20:48.176 3632-3632/jp.takesi.mcpebackup E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: jp.takesi.mcpebackup, PID: 3632
                                                                android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/MCPEBackups/tmp/MCPEBackup.apk exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
                                                                    at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1932)
                                                                    at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2348)
                                                                    at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9328)
                                                                    at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9282)
                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1591)
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4298)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4256)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4607)
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4575)
                                                                    at jp.takesi.mcpebackup.MainActivity.download(MainActivity.java:412)
                                                                    at jp.takesi.mcpebackup.MainActivity$6$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:368)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:161)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6440)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:746)
```

勿論、別スレッドで実行しています。
もし解決方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授のほどお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android 7.0 からパーミッションに変更がありました。
[ここのファイル システムのパーミッションの変更](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html?hl=ja#perm)を参考にしてください。

> パッケージ ドメイン以外の file:// URI
>   を渡すと、レシーバーがアクセスできないパスになる可能性があります。そのため、file:// URI
>   を渡そうとすると、FileUriExposedException がトリガーされます。プライベート
>   ファイルのコンテンツの共有には、FileProviderを使用することをお勧めします。

file://スキーマを直接扱うのではなくcontent://スキーマで扱ってください。
[FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html?hl=ja)を使う方法が独自Providerを用意する必要がないので簡単です。

Comment: ありがとうごさいます。ということはAndroid 7.0+の場合はcontent://で渡して、Android 7.0未満の場合はfile://で渡すということでいいでしょうか？

Comment: FileProviderはAPIレベル22から用意されています。APIレベル22はAndroid 5.1ですので、Android 5.1+であれば特に処理を変える必要はないでしょう。Android 5.1未満の場合はFileProviderが利用できないので処理を変える必要があると思います。

Comment: 5.1未満の場合、file://で渡す形式でやってみます

Comment: FileProviderはサポートライブラリでも提供されています。
https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html?hl=ja

Comment: @fkm 情報ありがとうございます。よくよく確認したら回答のリンク先自体がサポートライブラリのReferenceですね。FileProviderはOS標準のAPIには用意されていません。FileProviderはAPIレベル云々は関係なく、サポートライブラリのバージョン22から追加されていました。

Comment: @声優希望者たけし コメントで情報いただきました。適切なサポートライブラリを導入されていればAndroidのバージョンを気にする必要はなさそうです。